# PHP - Can't understand this code.

Tags: php

I have code here on a website I've taken over and I just can't get my head around it.

Could someone please explain to me what is exactly going on. I have a good knowledge of PHP but this baffles me.

Thanks

```
function decawave_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
if($vars['element']['#field_name'] == "field_resource_public_pdf" || $vars['element']['#field_name'] == "field_resource_pdf") {
$vars['items'][0]['#disclaimer'] = !empty($vars['element']['#object']->field_disclaimer) ? $vars['element']['#object']->field_disclaimer[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : 0;} 
}
```

Comment: What do you don't understand in this code?

Comment: Debug it on your own.

Comment: It's the shorthand if, isn't it?

Comment: Simple function, condition and ternary operator... nothing more.

Comment: The thing that throws me is the items in the square brackets.

Comment: for instance — what does $vars['element']['#field_name']. Is this an array ?

Comment: It might be a multidimensional array of objects that why the sqaure brackets

Comment: how can I read the contents of this array  ?

Comment: usually the multi-dimensional array would be recalled in the form $var[0] [1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If value of `$vars['element']['#field_name']` is equal (note [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) here) to `'field_resource_public_pdf'` or `$vars['element']['#field_name']` is equal (type juggling again) to `"field_resource_pdf"` string do the following:

Execute `empty($vars['element']['#object']->field_disclaimer)` (doc for [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)) function, if it returns false, than assign value of `$vars['element']['#object']->field_disclaimer[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` to `$vars['items'][0]['#disclaimer']`. 
Otherwise (if `[empty][2]($vars['element']['#object']->field_disclaimer)`returns true, assign `0` to `$vars['items'][0]['#disclaimer']` .

The code is pretty straightforward, but I'd note that function itself is written very poorly.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful information you have provided

Comment: Is there a better way to write this overall function ?

Comment: 1) It's generally a bad idea to modify arguments passed into function. You want to return desired value from function. 2) Your function knows too much about arguments being passed. Consider passing all your variables to function separately, instead of one object containing multiple values - from looking at method definition I should be able to understand what I need to pass to the method. Now your method accepts literally everything - but in fact it isn't designed to work with any params set - in fact there are some very specific restrictions in which fields should arguments contain